# How to allow LINK and UNLINK on IIS 10

Tags: http, web, iis

I'm exploring HTTP verbs like `LINK` and `UNLINK`. There is a simple website on IIS 10 for this purpose but looks like it doesn't allow these methods by default. I added a couple of rules in `Request Filtering` for verbs and still getting `405` error.

[image]

UPD
[image]

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <trace enabled="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="LINK" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="UNLINK" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What handler is there for those verbs? IIS doesn't handle `LINK` and `UNLINK` natively. Post your `applicationHost.config` (for both IIS Express and full-fat IIS) _and_ your application's `web.config`. How is your pool set-up?

Comment: Can you show me your rules? As far as I know, the only thing like LINK in IIS is url rewrite.

Comment: @Dai I haven't any handlers. I suppose first, I need just allow verbs. Posted `web.config`.  Where I can find IIS `applicationHost.config` for IIS ?

Comment: Whoa, slow down. You can't really add new verbs without first having a handler ready.

Comment: @samwu I added screen

Comment: @Dai `OPTIONS` and `TRACE` I added without handlers.  Didn't find manuals for implementing LINK and UNLINK.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` and `TRACE` verbs already have handlers built-in to IIS, that's why you don't need to add one. I assume you're intending for your application code to handle `LINK` and `UNLINK` then? If so, then please tell us how your application code works and receives the verb name from the host webserver... _that's kinda important_...

Comment: @Dai Well, I've been exploring HTTP verbs and it became interesting to me how `LINK` and `UNLINK` work. I created a single page website on IIS for tests. I found one [example](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-snell-link-method-01.html#rfc.section.5) but have no idea how allow and how implement these verbs via [ASP .Net](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFD_bUevLUqZ9OusToIf94vDmErPJoNG/view).

Comment: What version of ASP.NET? If you're using ASP.NET Core then just add a manual handler entry in your `Configure()` method when you setup your request pipeline.

Comment: @Dai I suppose, main problem is - I not completely understood how `Link` and `Unlink`  SHOULD work. Thought they are like `Trace` or kind of. Will try code some controller for them via `ASP.Net Core`.

Comment: A `Controller` won't necessarily be the right choice btw. When you use `Controller` your application code will start to make assumptions about the nature of the incoming HTTP requests. I suggest you use `.Use()` in `Configure` - it's _much simpler_ and gives you far more control.

Comment: @Dai Created a simple Asp. Net core csproj. Now there is no problem intercept http [requests](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFD_bUevLUqZ9OusToIf94vDmErPJoNG/edit). But why I'm getting 404 in [response](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SBvne5-1_2CC4Y6rlab6VG1g-ZzprW4g/edit) ?

Comment: You're getting HTTP 404 because none of your handlers are actually _handling_ the request and generating a response.

Comment: @Dai But `GET` returns my image, without handler.

Comment: That's because IIS's built-in `StaticFileHandler` handles it when ASP.NET Core doesn't. IIS has its own request-pipeline that's entirely separate from ASP.NET Core (of course, IIS' `StaticFileHandler` _doesn't_ handle `LINK` and `UNLINK` but it does handle `GET`).

Comment: @Dai In [this specification](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-snell-link-method-01.html) I met next message `The LINK method MAY be overridden by human intervention on the origin server`. As I understand, that means that origin server should implements `LINK` and `UNLINK` by default, isn't it ?

Comment: @Сергей I don't know. I haven't read the `LINK`/`UNLINK` specs/RFCs - and I'm not in a mood to read it now either.